# How to create dynamic library frameworks for iphone

Tags: iphone, sdk

I want know about how to create dynamic library frameworks for iphone..
Any ideas about this..please guide me...

Answer (score 5):

Dynamic linking is forbidden if you want to deliver to the App Store (apart of the Apple provided libraries and frameworks, of course). Only static linking of external libraries is allowed by Apple.

**Edit:** *(quoting myself from a comment to a different question)* The reason is security: since a dynamic library can be loaded and unloaded at runtime you could download additional executable code and load it (think plug-in). This could get compromised by a hacker and then having malicious code executing on your phone is a very bad thing. It would also make it possible to add unapproved features to an approved app. In short: in this environment, Apple considers dynamic linking to be a Pandoras box that must be strictly controlled, otherwise it could compromise security and I agree that it does make sense on the phone.

Answer (score 0):

This simply isn't supported for various reasons.

Use static libraries instead, or compile the source directly into your project.

Comment: Well, it is supported but you'll get rejected.